# Exporting array from MongoDB through Data Factory

Tags: mongodb, export, azure-data-factory

I have a MongoDB Atlas collection of service tickets that were sent via JSON.  I have imported them using an Azure Data Factory pipeline and have an output to CSV pipeline, also in ADF.  For the most part this is working fine, however one of the mapping needs to include all worklog-type entries into ONE cell using the "body" object from an array called "comments".  The format of the array is as such:  Comments -> 0 -> body, where the 0 is the first entry, 1 would be the second, 2 the third, etc.  There are also other objects besides the "body", such as "id", "created_at", etc. but they are not needed.

Currently, I can pull the body of each entry into their own cell using this format in the mapping:
$['comments'][0]['body'] --> body
$['comments'][1]['body'] --> body1

Is there a way in ADF to concatenate all of the comments per ticket into one field mapping?  I understand there are coding ways to combine things but the client is adamant about keeping it clean and just going through ADF.  I can't seem to figure out a format to get these all together in one mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection reference option in copy data activity mappings and select the JSON path to copy the JSON array object into multiple rows in a single field/column. This is only supported when you have a single-level hierarchy.

[image]

Output:

[image]